# passing char array to function from scanf in c

Tags: c, scanf

I have following function in c code

```
void analyze_text(char text[]) {
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < text_length || text[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    ...
    }
}
```

In main function i would like to pass some string to it. If i do something like this

```
char text[4000] = "some text here";
analyze_text(text);
```

this is cool and do the goal, but i would like to have some user input present and I am not sure how to get char[] out of it. I tried following 2 and none of them seemed to work:

```
char text[4000];
scanf("%s",text);
analyze_text(text);
```

OR

```
char text[4000];
int c;
int count=0;
c = getchar();
count = 0;
while ((count < 4000) && (c != EOF)) {
    text[count] = c;
    ++count;
    c = getchar();
}
analyze_text(text);
```

I know that the first one should return pointer to char array, but second one should return char array itself, or not?

Its been like 10 years since i havent been working with c/c++. Can anybody give me some hint please?

## update (whole function):

```
void analyze_text(char text[]) {
    int printable_text_length = 0;
    int text_length = strlen(text);
    int word_count = 0;
    int sentence_count = 0;
    int in_sentence = 0;
    int in_word = 0;
    int count[ASCII_SIZE] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < text_length || text[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        int c = text[i];
        if (!isspace(c)) {
            printable_text_length++;
        }
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            in_word = 1;
            in_sentence = 1;
            count[tolower(c)]++;
        }
        if (text[i] == ' ' && text[i + 1] != ' ' && in_word==1) {
            word_count++;
            in_word = 0;
        }
        if (text[i] == '.' && in_sentence==1) {
            sentence_count++;
            in_sentence = 0;
        }
    }
    if (in_word == 1) { word_count++; }
    if (in_sentence == 1) { sentence_count++; }

    char charIndexes[ASCII_SIZE];
    for (int i = 97; i <= 122; i++) {
        charIndexes[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i=97; i <= 122; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= 122; j++) {
            if (count[i] > count[j]) {
                int temp = count[j];
                count[j] = count[i];
                count[i] = temp;
                int temp2 = charIndexes[j];
                charIndexes[j] = charIndexes[i];
                charIndexes[i] = temp2;
            }
        }
    }
...printf...
}
```

Comment: There's no difference. `analyze_text()` works the same regardless of how you filled in the variable.

Comment: Where do you set `text_length`? You should use `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: The last code doesn't null-terminate the array.

Comment: You cannot return arrays. Only pointers.

Comment: so how can i get something to work with like charvar = "some text" ?

Comment: As long as the function doesn't modify the array, you just call `analyze_text(charvar)`.

Comment: What is the problem. You are asking for hint - hint for what ?

Comment: I mean. Look at update... I inserted whole function. Problem is that i dont know how to create user input into variable to work with my function. If i hard code something to variable it is working. But i would like to read it from console... And i cant make it work

Comment: It still isn't clear what your question is. All your approaches will work, except the third one where you need to add a null terminator to the array.

Comment: @interjay actually its not like that. It throws some weird error (-xxxxxxx digits as return value). also this "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Suppression State
Error C4996 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with

```
char text[4000];
scanf("%s",text);
analyze_text(text);
```

is that `scanf` identifies space-separated chunks, so you'll only read the first one.

In order to read up to a whole line from the user, try `fgets`:

```
char text[4000];
fgets(text, 4000, stdin);
analyze_text(text);
```

You may want to check the return value of `fgets` for error detection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dyanamic array of `char` to pass it into the function.
Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
void analyze_text(char* text) {


    for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("%c\n",text[i] );
    }
}
int main() {

    char* text  = (char *)malloc(4000 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", text);
    analyze_text(text);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the output with input = 'abhishek'

```
a
b
h
i
s
h
e
k
```

remember that `strlen` in dyanamc array will not give the length of input array.

Comment: `scanf("%s", text);` has same trouble as the now obsolete `gets()`: buffer over run.  `scanf("%3999s", text);` would prevent that.

Comment: this does not work for me as well " exited with code -1073741819"